# How do I automatically make python tkinter Entry automatically?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I've been making Entries in python tkinter but I found it out very inefficient to make every individual Entries. How can I make Entries automatically and get the values of all the Entries individually?

```
entry_word1 = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
        entry_word1.grid(column=1, row=0)
        entry_word2 = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
        entry_word2.grid(column=1, row=1)
        entry_word3 = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
        entry_word3.grid(column=1, row=2)
        entry_word4 = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
        entry_word4.grid(column=1, row=3)
        entry_word5 = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
        entry_word5.grid(column=1, row=4)
        entry_word6 = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
        entry_word6.grid(column=1, row=5)
        entry_word7 = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
        entry_word7.grid(column=1, row=6)
        entry_word8 = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
        entry_word8.grid(column=1, row=7)
        entry_word9 = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
        entry_word9.grid(column=1, row=8)
        entry_word10 = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
        entry_word10.grid(column=1, row=9)
```

Comment: Use a `list` for all of the entries and make them in a `for` loop.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Please edit your question and include your code as text (formatted in a code block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of storing `Entry` objects **without** using list

and accessing them by binding each one to a Return Key

with a callback to function `getdata`

Any Entry widget can be found using `getEntry` using index value.

```py
import tkinter

master = tkinter.Tk()

second_frame = tkinter.Frame(master)
second_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

def getdata(ev):
    print(ev.widget.get())

def getEntry( a ):
    return list( second_frame.children.values() )[ a ]

for a in range(10):
    b = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
    b.grid(row=a, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    # important to bind each one for access
    b.bind('<Return>', getdata)

master.resizable(False, False)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's a good idea to store all of the widgets in a list. Right now your code will make it hard for the program to get the value of all entries when the user presses `<Return>`. So imagine an input form and the user presses `<Return>` to submit all of the data.

Comment: Any Entry can be found easily with `getEntry`, so list is not necessary.

Comment: Instead of having your own list, you convert the dictionary of children to a list then index it. Also you also had to put the entries in a frame to make it work. That is so inefficient and slow. So basically you are using the frame only for the list of the entries. What's the problem with a normal list?

Comment: Unnecessary overhead, unless accessing `Entry` objects directly is needed. There are many ways to implement these things, that's the power of Python .

Comment: What overhead??? You are creating a frame and then using the children that it stores in itself (`second_frame.children.values()`). For that to work there is dictionary inside `second_frame`. That means that you are using a dictionary instead of a list. That's inefficient. Also there are many ways to implement things in python, but most ways are terrible.

Comment: Yes but only if you have to use it. Storing references to `Entry` a list is just dead weight - unless you have to use it. `.children' attribute is already there so there's no cost.

Comment: 48 bytes per entry. That is small enough to not even matter. Also what if OP has more widgets inside `second_frame`? Your code will stop working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234664/discussion-between-derek-and-thelizzard).